# Cocos2dx - remove "DONE" button above soft keyboard in android

Tags: android, android-layout, cocos2d-x, android-softkeyboard

I have checked some of the question that how to add "DONE" button above soft keyboard but there is no any questions that how to remove that button. when I click on any EditText in the app and once soft keyboard open that "DONE" button will display. I want to hide or don't want to display that button.

Another most important thing is application is developed on **"Cocos2dx Game Engine"** and exported. Now I have opened that exported project in [Android Studio Arctic Fox 2020.3.1](https://developer.android.com/studio) and run the project, so there is no any XML files for layout design.

I have checked these are the question and other article/blog also related to this. [Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16411056/how-to-adjust-layout-when-soft-keyboard-appears), [Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4207880/android-how-do-i-prevent-the-soft-keyboard-from-pushing-my-view-up), [Question 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1964789/move-layouts-up-when-soft-keyboard-is-shown), [Question 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7300497/adjust-layout-when-soft-keyboard-is-on), [Question 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21201569/android-resize-only-parts-of-view-with-soft-keyboard-on-screen), [Question 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47506415/how-to-adjust-the-dialog-size-when-keyboard-is-open), [Question 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7417123/android-how-to-adjust-layout-in-full-screen-mode-when-softkeyboard-is-visible), [Question 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5307264/how-to-prevent-soft-keyboard-from-resizing-background-image), [Question 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19554939/scroll-the-screen-up-when-keyboard-appears), [Question 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15323758/android-how-to-push-button-above-soft-keyboard) and [Article 1](https://yatmanwong.medium.com/android-how-to-pan-the-page-up-more-25fc5c542a97), [Article 2](https://medium.com/@madalinnita/android-how-to-move-views-above-keyboard-when-its-opened-quick-secure-solution-90188c4d7b15) etc.

Below is normal screen

[image]

and once soft keyboard is opened it will be displayed as below

[image]

I have tested app on more then 10+ devices and also in Android 8.1, Android 10, Android 11 but this thing happen only in Samsung a52 device.

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try using a 3rd party keyboard and see what happens.  If it doesn't happen with the 3rd party one, it's something with the default keyboard on that model (Samsung has used their own keyboard on various models over the years) and there won't be much you can do about it.  I'm kind of wondering if somehow the keyboard enabled Extract View mode, even though that generally happens only on landscape.  If it did, there's no way for you to stop it.

Comment: @GabeSechan let me do as you suggest, also let me know do you know any good 3rd party library.